# Error while updating location of the azure api management service

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

I'm trying to update the region of the created azure management api service instance using the rest api.

**URL -** 
https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/b0474e6c-9d1c-4b84-87f5-27ef6aad5e5e/resourceGroups/res1/providers/Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/cloud1?api-version=2017-03-01

**Body**

```
{
    "parameters": {
        "serviceName": "cloud1",
        "resourceGroupName": "res1",
        "api-version": "2017-03-01",
        "subscriptionId": "b0474e6c-9d1c-4b84-87f5-27ef6aad5e5e",
        "parameters": {
            "location": "North Central US"
        }
    },
    "responses": {
        "200": {
            "id": "/subscriptions/b0474e6c-9d1c-4b84-87f5-27ef6aad5e5e/resourceGroups/res1/providers/Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/cloud1",
            "name": "",
            "type": "Microsoft.ApiManagement/service",
            "tags": {},
            "location": "Central US",
            "etag": "AAAAAACYO/A=",
            "properties": {
                "publisherEmail": "",
                "publisherName": "",
                "notificationSenderEmail": "apimgmt-noreply@mail.windowsazure.com",
                "provisioningState": "Succeeded",
                "targetProvisioningState": "",
                "createdAtUtc": "2017-02-14T04:33:06.0312071Z",
                "gatewayUrl": "https://cloud1.azure-api.net",
                "portalUrl": "https://cloud1.portal.azure-api.net",
                "managementApiUrl": "https://cloud1.management.azure-api.net",
                "scmUrl": "https://cloud1.scm.azure-api.net",
                "hostnameConfigurations": [],
                "staticIps": [
                    "40.66.160.152"
                ],
                "additionalLocations": null,
                "virtualNetworkConfiguration": null,
                "customProperties": null,
                "virtualNetworkType": "None"
            },
            "sku": {
                "name": "Developer",
                "capacity": 1
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Headers**

Authorization Bearer 
Content-Type  application/json

I'm getting below error.

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "InvalidRequestContent",
    "message": "The request content was invalid and could not be deserialized: 'Could not find member 'parameters' on object of type 'ResourceDefinition'. Path 'parameters', line 2, position 15.'."
  }
}
```

Am I doing anything wrong??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The payload is invalid, it should be the same as with service creation:

```
{
  "location": "westus",
  "properties": {
    "publisherEmail": "...",
    "publisherName": "..."
  },
  "sku": {
    "name": "Developer",
    "capacity": 1
  }
}
```

But on top of that it is not supported to change master region of APIM service, you'll have to create new service and delete old one.